# why does file say "no magic" when a file consists of nothing but a single ASCII character?

Tags: bash, file, ascii

When a file contains nothing but a single space, linefeed, or ASCII letter, why does the file command say it is "no magic"?
Clobber the file with two of the same character,
and then file calls it ASCII.

What would a very small file **with** magic be?
Why would one create it and what would it be used for?

```
> /bin/rm junk
> printf ' ' > junk; file junk
junk: very short file (no magic)
> echo  > junk; file junk
junk: very short file (no magic)
> printf 'd' > junk; file junk
junk: very short file (no magic)
> printf 'dd' > junk; file junk
junk: ASCII text, with no line terminators
```

The following post seems related; it was closed for lacking details or clarity:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393288/explain-please-what-is-a-magic-file-in-unix

But I'm not asking what magic is or how to make a file magic.
I ask why `file` says "no magic" for a one-byte file but not for a two-byte file.

Comment: There is a set of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) that are used by file formats to specify their contents. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) is a list. The `file` tool is looking for those "magic" numbers.

Comment: 'magic' is the bytes than can reveal which type of files the `file` command look-up. By example, a `wav` audio file begin with `RIFF***@**@WAVE`

Comment: Because that's how it was written? "Magic" has no formal definition, but indeed, it makes very little sense to attempt to classify a one-byte file as anything at all. Even a two-byte file is a bit dubious, but at least there are multiple two-byte signatures and eliminating those would allow you to "conclude" it's ASCII, I suppose.

Comment: ... if it makes very little sense to attempt to classify a one-byte file, why are you trying to do it??? What was your intention when using `file` in this situation?

Comment: `why file says "no magic" for a one-byte file but not for a two-byte file.` Because source code of file is "if one byte then nomagic else .."? I do not understand what kind of answer do you expect to get? `What would a very small file with magic be? Why would one create it and what would it be used for?` I do not undersatnd the questions. A very small file with magic would be a very small file with certain sequence of bytes. It would be used to detect the file format, depending exactly on what "magic" would it be.

Comment: An example of a two-byte file that's classified as something other than ASCII can be obtained with `printf '\xff\xfe'`, which will be "detected" as UTF-16 LE text due to the telltale BOM. None of the popular binary formats that happen to start with a two-letter code appear to be detected as such, probably because this would cause too many false positives and the checks are a bit more sensitive than that.

Comment: You said you're not asking for what magic is, but do you _know_ what it is in this context? I suspect that _would_ answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

> why file says "no magic" for a one-byte file but not for a two-byte file.

Because `file` program was written to do exactly that.

From https://github.com/file/file/blob/c49972ddb4933ee6edc4a2abc7f36f6a42d47300/src/funcs.c#L338 :

```
if (nb == 0) {
    def = "empty";
    goto simple;
} else if (nb == 1) {
    def = "very short file (no magic)";
    goto simple;
}
```